# Why cube is not getting generated properly

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have a cube which makes some angle with X axis.

For that I have written my cube vertices like this:

```
cubeX=[

        0 cosd(theta) (cosd(theta)+sind(theta)) sind(theta) %bottom

        0 cosd(theta) (cosd(theta)+sind(theta)) sind(theta) %top

        0 cosd(theta) cosd(theta) 0 %front

        0 cosd(theta) cosd(theta) 0 %back

        sind(theta) 0 0 sind(theta) % left

        (cosd(theta)+sind(theta)) cosd(theta) cosd(theta) (cosd(theta)+sind(theta)) % right

        ]*side;

cubeY=[

        0 -sind(theta) (cosd(theta)-sind(theta)) cosd(theta) %bottom

        0 -sind(theta) (cosd(theta)-sind(theta)) cosd(theta) %top

        0 -sind(theta) -sind(theta) 0 %front

        0 -sind(theta) -sind(theta) 0 %back

        cosd(theta) 0 0 cosd(theta) %left

        (cosd(theta)-sind(theta)) -sind(theta) -sind(theta) (cosd(theta)-sind(theta)) %right

        ]*side;


cubeZ=[

        0 0 0 0 %bottom

        1 1 1 1 %top

        0 0 1 1

        0 0 1 1

        0 0 1 1

        0 0 1 1

        ]*side;
```

But when I plot this using `plot3(cubeX,cubeY,cubeZ)`
one line i.e. bottom right line is not drawn

Can someone please explain what I maybe doing wrong

[image: cube generated by matlab]

Also attached is the image which shows the angle with X axis
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close each one of your faces...meaning that each square that you're drawing needs 5 points instead of 4.  The last point (the 5th point) should be the same as the first point.  For example:

```
cubeX=[

        0 cosd(theta) (cosd(theta)+sind(theta)) sind(theta) 0  %bottom

        0 cosd(theta) (cosd(theta)+sind(theta)) sind(theta) 0 %top

        0 cosd(theta) cosd(theta) 0  0 %front

        0 cosd(theta) cosd(theta) 0 0 %back

        sind(theta) 0 0 sind(theta) sind(theta) % left

        (cosd(theta)+sind(theta)) cosd(theta) cosd(theta) (cosd(theta)+sind(theta)) (cosd(theta)+sind(theta)) % right

        ]*side;
```

Without the extra point, your squares will have four points but only 3 lines.  Adding the extra point will give your squares four lines, which will close them off.  This should result in drawing your missing line.

Also, your cubeX, cubeY, and cubeZ might be the wrong shape for what you intend.  I would expect them to have 4 (now 5) rows and 6 columns.  You might try transposing them...

```
plot3(cubeX',cubeY',cubeZ')
```